# How to save the edge list of igraph object with the predefined layout?

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

I have read the [R igraph - save layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927099/r-igraph-save-layout), but in my case it is requared to save positions of begin's and end's edges into a file with the edge list together.

I have a `tree` igraph object and predefined `mylayout` layout on the plane.

```
tree <- make_tree(5, 2, mode = "undirected")
mylayout <- matrix(c(1, 2, 0, 3, 2, 
                     1, 2, 0, 2, 3), ncol=2)
```

I have add a new attribute `name`

```
tree <- make_tree(5, 2, mode = "undirected") %>% 
            set_vertex_attr("name", value = seq(1:vcount(tree)))
```

and I get the edge list of graph via the `get.edgelist()` function, and I am going to use `name` attribute:

```
   df1 <- data.frame(V1 = get.edgelist(tree)[,1], 
                  V2 = get.edgelist(tree)[,2], 
#           V1_x = mylayout[as.integer(names(V(tree))), 1],
#           V1_y = mylayout[as.integer(names(V(tree))), 2],
#           V2_x = mylayout[, 1],
#           V2_y = mylayout[, 2],
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

**Question.** How to match the nodes positions with the begin's and end's positions of edges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's an existing way to do this, but it's not too much work to write a helper function to do this

```
join_layout <- function(g, layout) {
  edges <- as_edgelist(g)
  idx1 <- match(edges[,1], V(g)$name)
  idx2 <- match(edges[,2], V(g)$name)
  result <- cbind(data.frame(edges),
        layout[idx1, ],
        layout[idx2, ]
  )
  names(result) <- c("V1", "V2", "V1_x", "V1_y", "V2_x","V2_y")
  result
}
```

Basically we use `match()` to match up the vertex names to rows in the layout matrix. You call it by passing in the `igraph` object and your layout

```
join_layout(tree, mylayout)
#   V1 V2 V1_x V1_y V2_x V2_y
# 1  1  2    1    1    2    2
# 2  1  3    1    1    0    0
# 3  2  4    2    2    3    2
# 4  2  5    2    2    2    3
```

Comment: your code works. I have tried to create the graph from the result date.frame, but have a problem with layout. Is it an optimal way to save edge's relations and node's positions?

Comment: I hope I found the problem for common case, I open the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68858311/how-to-define-the-order-of-rows-before-writing-to-file

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
get.data.frame(tree) %>%
  cbind(
    split(
      data.frame(mylayout)[match(unlist(.), 1:nrow(mylayout)), ],
      c(col(.))
    )
  )
```

which gives

```
  from to 1.X1 1.X2 2.X1 2.X2
1    1  2    1    1    2    2
2    1  3    1    1    0    0
3    2  4    2    2    3    2
4    2  5    2    2    2    3
```

Comment: your code works on the my toy example. Now I try to rewrite it on the common case. My problem is the order of edges and nodes. In the output one can see ordered rows, but in common case I have another order.